# Our code is behind a firewall and we don't want to put source code in cloud. Are there any good CI/CD using local agents for Azure/Github actions

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, azure, continuous-deployment, software-recommendation, github-actions

Our source code is in our servers and we don't have approval to put it in cloud.

We don't have a seamless CI/CD. Can we use Azure pipeline agents or any local agents to build our code and only export the build artifacts to cloud and continue with CD?

We are deploying our applications in Azure but not the source code.

Please suggest a good CI/CD for us.

Comment: Hi @user2566272, in order to help your question more easily be answered, I recommend you edit the title so it is easier for others to search for and quickly analyze if it is a question they have knowledge of. Something such as "Can I use local agents with GitHub Actions?" or "Cloning a local repository with a GitHub Actions runner". In addition, I would also recommend you would narrow down your question to a more specific use case. Narrowing it down to a specific technology or a particular use case helps with that. If you need, feel free to break it up into multiple questions :)

Comment: On-prem solutions will require money/time/elbow grease.  What is your budget for these?

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps also has a solution called Azure DevOps Server. It allows you to host you source code on-prem, and also build on-prem. Depending on your needs you could store your artifact on-prem or in the cloud and either way, it would allow you to deploy in the cloud.

So, yes, it is possible, but it will take quite some effort. At least you'll need a server for Azure DevOps Server, depending on the size another one for your database, and another one for your build and release agents. It will also take some effort to put together the pipelines and other infrastructure required, but if you really need to keep your sourcecode and builds on-prem this will definitely work for you.

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your entire build pipeline inside your network, so your version control and build server are all running behind the firewall.

There is a reasonable amount of effort in doing this, as you are now running infrastructure and updating the tooling on top of writing the software. This is why so many organizations are using cloud offerings such as [GitHub](https://github.com/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), and [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/devops/). It does work out far cheaper and the each provide a trust centre to help the organization make a decision.

You would just need to make sure that the final stage of the build pipeline could access the "external" location where you plan to store the artefact or deploy the software to, so there would still be some network rules to set up your allow list for the outbound part of this process.